# Inplace construction in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, memory, ffi

If I have a buffer of memory allocated by malloc, is it possible to instantiate a value like `Just 3` into the buffer *without copying it* (given I have a pointer to it)?

Analogous to `foo = new (ptr) Class()` in C++.

Comment: Are you talking about [`Foreign.Marshal.Alloc.malloc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:malloc), or some bytes allocated by [`malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) accessible via the FFI?

Comment: More like `mallocBytes`.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to manage the memory of "normal" Haskell objects, which is not going to work very well.

Comment: Do clarify what others are warning against: GHC's garbage collector actually *moves* objects in memory. This means that having pointers from non-GC handled memory to GC'ed objects promises almost certain horrible disaster.

Comment: Realized 1 minute too late I'd forgotten to distinguish *pinned* objects, which are GC'ed but not moved. But they are not the default kind of values, and values such as `Just 3` cannot be made pinned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types in the class [`Storable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#t:Storable) can be marshalled into raw memory. To marshal a type like `Maybe` you will need to write an encoding to and from an already-existing type. For example, a product of the tag and the value. The value stored in the `Just` case should also be `Storable`.

Comment: Is it possible without copying it? And could I coerce these back into regular types and pass them around?

Comment: You can't coerce them into regular Haskell values without copying. Anything that has pinned/storable semantics really has a different type. Native storable types, like `ByteString` can be manipulated without copying, however.